# When using state-pattern in XML parsing, Is it wise to unit test different "state" classes

Tags: ios, xml, unit-testing, state-pattern

I am writing unit tests and want to test parsing of an XML document. 
To parse not too complicated XML document I use standard `NSXMLParser` and state pattern.

I will test proper parsing of a document by checking result object created by `NSXMLParserDelegate`. I will have some proper XML files and some improper ones.

Should I also check each state-class separately, or is checking only final result enough ?

**Added after Edit**
By state-class I mean ConcreteState in [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).
My `NSXMLParserDelegate` has its own delegates which have only three methods:
 - didStartElement
 - didEndElemenn
 - foundCharacters

Each of my *State-class* implements above methods and stores data or,and changes `NSXMLParserDelegate` state to another *State-class*.
I think that this is quite standard ...

My question is:
Should I unit test each *State-class* (*ConcreteState*) or is it enough to test only parsing of specially prepared correct and incorrect XML files?

Comment: This is rather broad and unclear.  What is a "state-class"?

Comment: @JimGarrison I added some more explanation. Hope it is more clear now